# Uninstall the app installed using "Test Installtion Flow" option

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am testing our app for listing it under google market place, while testing App got installed when i clicked "Test Installtion Flow", But I am not getting option to uninstall it. However the third party apps installed from google marketplace I am able to uninstall.
Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

From this [FAQ page](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/faq#how_can_i_manage_and_uninstall_the_applications_i_have_installed_from_the_marketplace) questioned, **"How can I manage and uninstall the applications I have installed from the Marketplace?"**

It is stated here that by clicking on "Manage Apps" on the top right of the Marketplace, users can view the applications they have installed. From there they can rate, review and uninstall applications **(unless admin-installed)**.

Hope it helps you.